# Java: check if number belongs to Fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, fibonacci

I'm supposed to write a code which checks if a given number belongs to the Fibonacci sequence. After a few hours of hard work this is what i came up with:

```
public class TP2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static boolean ehFibonacci(int n) {
        int fib1 = 0;
        int fib2 = 1;
        do {
            int saveFib1 = fib1;
            fib1 = fib2;
            fib2 = saveFib1 + fib2;
            }
        while (fib2 <= n);

        if (fib2 == n)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 8;
        System.out.println(ehFibonacci(n));

    }
}
```

I must be doing something wrong, because it always returns "false". Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: On a side note: I find using `do {} while()` loops is not very common practice these days. I find using a normal `while() {}` loop easier to read, because you know under which conditions the code you will read afterwards will be executed. As a small bonus it also saves one line of code. So unless you need to have your code executed at least one time and can't easily make your condition reflect that, using a normal while loop would be the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

You continue the loop while `fib2 <= n`, so when you are out of the loop, fib2 is always `> n`, and so it returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param args
 */

public static boolean ehFibonacci(int n) {
    int fib1 = 0;
    int fib2 = 1;
    do {
        int saveFib1 = fib1;
        fib1 = fib2;
        fib2 = saveFib1 + fib2;
        }
    while (fib2 < n);

    if (fib2 == n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    System.out.println(ehFibonacci(n));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. I am not sure about efficiency..but this is a foolproof program,

```
public class isANumberFibonacci {

public static int fibonacci(int seriesLength) {
    if (seriesLength == 1 || seriesLength == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fibonacci(seriesLength - 1) + fibonacci(seriesLength - 2);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int number = 4101;
    int i = 1;
    while (i > 0) {
        int fibnumber = fibonacci(i);
        if (fibnumber != number) {
            if (fibnumber > number) {
                System.out.println("Not fib");
                break;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The number is fibonacci");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can also use perfect square to check whether your number is Fibonacci or not. you can find the code and some explanation at [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-number-fibonacci-number/).
you can also see [stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/checking-if-a-number-is-a-fibonacci-or-not/10002#10002) for the math behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner but this code runs perfectly fine without any issues. Checked with test cases hopefully it'll solve your query.

```
public static boolean checkMember(int n) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    boolean isTrue = true;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        x = y;
        y = sum;
        sum = x + y;
        if (sum == n) {
            isTrue=true;
            break;
        } else {
            isTrue=false;
        }
    }
    return isTrue;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print(checkMember(n));

}
```